# Mongoose duplicating entries after post data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hey :] after trying to send data through a `api.post('/send/remember-me', function (req, res)` the entries arrive duplicate in my collections, see in below

```
rememberMe  1   false   8.03 KB 
remembermes 1   false   16.08 KB
```

I'm doing my schema this way:

Remember.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var rememberMeModel = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    }
});

var rememberMe = module.exports = mongoose.model('rememberMe', rememberMeModel);
```

index.js

```
var rememberMe = require('./models/Remember');

api.post('/send/remember-me', function (req, res) {
  var rememberCredential = new rememberMe();
  rememberCredential.username = req.body.username;

  rememberCredential.save( function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

remember-me.html

```
            <form action="/send/remember-me" method="post">
                <div class="input-field col s12 l6">
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="validate">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" value="Submit">Testar
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                </button>
            </form>
```

Thank for helping me!

Comment: Can you add a sample of what is being duplicated in the question?

Comment: tried using only `mongoose` or also used `mongo shell` because for `mongoose` collection name should be `remembermes` and for `mongo shell` can be any name that you gave

Answer (score 0):

**Try this hope it works**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var rememberMeModel = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    } }); module.exports = mongoose.model('rememberMe', rememberMeModel);
```

**instead of**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var rememberMeModel = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    }
});

var rememberMe = module.exports = mongoose.model('rememberMe', rememberMeModel);
```